Call Flutter Code from Android Home Widget when app is not running
Is it possible to trigger Flutter code from Android Home Widget when the app is not running? For example a refresh button that will retrieve some data and process it using some Flutter packages that involves Geolocation and Geocoding

No dear, you cannot do this because flutter can not interact with native features directly, but you can do it using hybrid/native coding like using java. And does not about that will it work when flutter app is stopped or not in running state
